# Example of dynamic thread pool in boost::asio

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm going to implement boost::asio server with a thread pool using single `io_service` ( [HTTP Server 3
example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) ). `io_service` will be bound to unix domain socket and pass requests going from connections on this socket to different threads. In order to reduce resource consumption I want to make the thread pool dynamic.

Here is a concept. Firstly a single thread is created. When a request arrives and server sees that there is no idle thread in a pool it creates a new thread and passes the request to it. The server can create up to some maximum number of threads. Ideally it should have functinality of suspending threads which are idle for some time.

Did somebody make something similar? Or maybe somebody has a relevant example?

As for me, I guess I should somehow override `io_service.dispatch` to achieve that.

Answer (score 8):

There may be a few challenges with the initial approach:

- `boost::asio::io_service` is not intended to be derived from or reimplemented.  Note the lack of virtual functions.
- If your thread library does not provide the ability to query a thread's state, then state information needs to be managed separately.

An alternative  solution is to post a job into the `io_service`, then check how long it sat in the `io_service`.  If the time delta between when it was ready-to-run and when it was actually ran is above a certain threshold, then this indicates there are more jobs in the queue than threads servicing the queue.  A major benefit to this is that the dynamic thread pool growth logic becomes decoupled from other logic.

Here is an example that accomplishes this by using the `deadline_timer`.

- Set `deadline_timer` to expire `3` seconds from now.
- Asynchronously wait on the `deadline_timer`.  The handler will be ready-to-run `3` seconds from when the `deadline_timer` was set.
- In the asynchronous handler, check the current time relative to when the timer was set to expire.  If it is greater than `2` seconds, then the `io_service` queue is backing up, so add a thread to the thread pool.

Example:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class thread_pool_checker
  : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:

  thread_pool_checker( boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                       boost::thread_group& threads,
                       unsigned int max_threads,
                       long threshold_seconds,
                       long periodic_seconds )
    : io_service_( io_service ),
      timer_( io_service ),
      threads_( threads ),
      max_threads_( max_threads ),
      threshold_seconds_( threshold_seconds ),
      periodic_seconds_( periodic_seconds )
    {
      schedule_check();
    }

private:

  void schedule_check();
  void on_check( const boost::system::error_code& error );

private:

  boost::asio::io_service&    io_service_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
  boost::thread_group&        threads_;
  unsigned int                max_threads_;
  long                        threshold_seconds_;
  long                        periodic_seconds_;
};

void thread_pool_checker::schedule_check()
{
  // Thread pool is already at max size.
  if ( max_threads_ <= threads_.size() )
  {
    std::cout << "Thread pool has reached its max.  Example will shutdown."
              << std::endl;
    io_service_.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Schedule check to see if pool needs to increase.
  std::cout << "Will check if pool needs to increase in " 
            << periodic_seconds_ << " seconds." << std::endl;
  timer_.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds( periodic_seconds_ ) );
  timer_.async_wait( 
    boost::bind( &thread_pool_checker::on_check, this,
                 boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
}

void thread_pool_checker::on_check( const boost::system::error_code& error )
{
  // On error, return early.
  if ( error ) return;

  // Check how long this job was waiting in the service queue.  This
  // returns the expiration time relative to now.  Thus, if it expired
  // 7 seconds ago, then the delta time is -7 seconds.
  boost::posix_time::time_duration delta = timer_.expires_from_now();
  long wait_in_seconds = -delta.seconds();

  // If the time delta is greater than the threshold, then the job
  // remained in the service queue for too long, so increase the
  // thread pool.
  std::cout << "Job job sat in queue for " 
            << wait_in_seconds << " seconds." << std::endl;
  if ( threshold_seconds_ < wait_in_seconds )
  {
    std::cout << "Increasing thread pool." << std::endl;
    threads_.create_thread(
      boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run,
                   &io_service_ ) );
  }

  // Otherwise, schedule another pool check.
  schedule_check();
}

// Busy work functions.
void busy_work( boost::asio::io_service&,
                unsigned int );

void add_busy_work( boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                    unsigned int count )
{
  io_service.post(
    boost::bind( busy_work,
                 boost::ref( io_service ),
                 count ) );
}

void busy_work( boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                unsigned int count )
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds( 5 ) );

  count += 1;

  // When the count is 3, spawn additional busy work.
  if ( 3 == count )
  {
    add_busy_work( io_service, 0 );
  }
  add_busy_work( io_service, count );
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

  // Create io service.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Add some busy work to the service.
  add_busy_work( io_service, 0 );

  // Create thread group and thread_pool_checker.
  boost::thread_group threads;
  thread_pool_checker checker( io_service, threads,
                               3,   // Max pool size.
                               2,   // Create thread if job waits for 2 sec.
                               3 ); // Check if pool needs to grow every 3 sec.

  // Start running the io service.
  io_service.run();

  threads.join_all();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 7 seconds.
Increasing thread pool.
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 0 seconds.
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 4 seconds.
Increasing thread pool.
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 0 seconds.
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 0 seconds.
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 0 seconds.
Will check if pool needs to increase in 3 seconds.
Job job sat in queue for 3 seconds.
Increasing thread pool.
Thread pool has reached its max.  Example will shutdown.
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, busy_work tasks may wait in a queue for seconds as well as pool checker even if maximum thread count wasn't reached yet because new threads are not created ahead of time. That makes this principle hardly usable because feature of being dynamic shouldn't degrade performance so much. It should make task execution longer just by time needed for a new thread creation compared to time needed with static pool. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @user484936: Your understanding is correct.  Pool growth occurs _after_ degradation has been detected; it is one of the simplier approaches to pooling and should not 'degrade performance'.  If you want to allocate threads _when you know_ that they are needed, then thread state needs to be managed, introducing overhead for all threads, and may require the state logic to be scattered throughout the code.  If you want to allocate threads _as you predict_ that they will be needed, then have a dedicated thread posting a job into the service, then do a timed wait for a response.

Comment: I am wondering what happens in a scenario where there is only one long running task executed and we needlessly add a thread to the pool when our timer fires. If there is actually no more event to process at that time then this approach seems to be inefficient to me. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I discover that post 8 years later. 
@russoue, using asio you have to code in order to not have a "long running task" in one thread, in other words you have to take care of that using post.

Comment: @TannerSansbury, great idea for growing the thread pool, but next step should be reducing the pool on low work load. IMHO that is not easily possible ...